# Windows Phone Context Menu Item Text Not Appearing

Tags: xaml, contextmenu, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone 8 app using XAML/C#. My app has an `ItemsControl` that relies on a data template. My `DataTemplate` looks like the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
  <Grid Margin="0,0,0,8">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" >
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
          <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="customerMenuItem" Foreground="White" Header="View Customer Profile" Click="customerMenuItem_Click" Tag="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" />
          </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" />
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1"><!-- Stuff here --></StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This `DataTemplate` is referenced in the main part of my XAML as shown here:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
  <ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Please note, the "toolkit" namespace comes from clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit. When I hold my finger (or mouse) on the `TextBlock`, a context menu appears. However, I never see the words "View Customer Profile". I just see a block box that represents the context menu itself. I know that the item is there though. I know because the `customerMenuItem_Click` event successfully fires. I have a `MessageBox` in there that shows the value of the Tag. That value is always correct. For some reason though the menu item text is not appearing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You put `Foreground = "White"`. Context menu is on white background. That is why you don't see your menu item.